# Isn't unordered_map only supposed to have two parameters?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, stl, unordered-map

This question is regarding finding colinear points from a bunch of points.

Firstly, I didn't understand how is `slopeMap` and unordered map? Isn't map only suppose to have a key and a value (`map<key, value>`)? In this particular code

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int,boost:: 
          hash<pair<int, int> > > slopeMap;
```

From my understanding, it has the pair as a key and an int after it, which should be the value, but then it doesn't exactly end there?

**THE FULL CODE:**

```
using namespace std; 

// method to find maximum colinear point 
int maxPointOnSameLine(vector< pair<int, int> > points) 
{ 


    int N = points.size(); 
      if (N < 2) 
        return N; 

    int maxPoint = 0; 
    int curMax, overlapPoints, verticalPoints; 

    // here since we are using unordered_map  
    // which is based on hash function  
    //But by default we don't have hash function for pairs 
    //so we'll use hash function defined in Boost library 
    unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int,boost:: 
              hash<pair<int, int> > > slopeMap; 

    // looping for each point 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    { 
        curMax = overlapPoints = verticalPoints = 0; 

        // looping from i + 1 to ignore same pair again 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) 
        { 
            // If both point are equal then just 
            // increase overlapPoint count 
            if (points[i] == points[j]) 
                overlapPoints++; 

            // If x co-ordinate is same, then both 
            // point are vertical to each other 
            else if (points[i].first == points[j].first) 
                verticalPoints++; 

            else
            { 
                int yDif = points[j].second - points[i].second; 
                int xDif = points[j].first - points[i].first; 
                int g = __gcd(xDif, yDif); 

                // reducing the difference by their gcd 
                yDif /= g; 
                xDif /= g; 

                // increasing the frequency of current slope 
                // in map 
                slopeMap[make_pair(yDif, xDif)]++; 
                curMax = max(curMax, slopeMap[make_pair(yDif, xDif)]); 
            } 

            curMax = max(curMax, verticalPoints); 
        } 

        // updating global maximum by current point's maximum 
        maxPoint = max(maxPoint, curMax + overlapPoints + 1); 

        // printf("maximum colinear point  
        // which contains current point  
        // are : %d\n", curMax + overlapPoints + 1); 
        slopeMap.clear(); 
    } 

    return maxPoint; 
}
```

// Driver code

```
int main() 
{ 
    const int N = 6; 
    int arr[N][2] = {{-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, 
                    {3, 3}, {3, 4}}; 

    vector< pair<int, int> > points; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        points.push_back(make_pair(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])); 

    cout << maxPointOnSameLine(points) << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

**WHERE**

```
Input : points[] = {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, 
                    {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4} 
Output : 4
Then maximum number of point which lie on same
line are 4, those point are {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2},
{3, 3}
```

I also wanted a logic-based suggestion. How could I modify this code so that, instead of returning a number that defines the max num of points colinear, to actually storing any point that is colinear in some form of a data structure that I may use later?

Sources: 
[Counting maximum points of the same line](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-maximum-points-on-same-line/)

Comment: correction
its max* instead of man in the second last line

Comment: You can always [edit] your question. No need to comment.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Questions are supposed to be self contained. When that external link rots the question will be useless to future readers. Put everything relevant *in* the question, please.

Comment: See [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) on cppreference.com. An unordered map is more than just a collection of key/values pairs. There is also hashing involved, which is what the 3rd template parameter is for

Comment: Noted. I am a new user so thanks for them tips.

Comment: Interesting (if pedantic) fun fact: There is no `unordered_map` in the Standard Template Library. There is one in the modern C++ Standard Library, though.

Comment: @user4581301 if you want to be super pedantic: the original standard template library had a `hash_map`, it just didnt make it into the standard

Comment: @user4581301 that's beyond pedantic and into useless territory. If you don't consider what's in the C++17 (and earlier) standard library part of what people in 2019 would term "STL", then I don't want to communicate any further. Come on, don't be stuck in C++98, *please*.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't map only suppose to have a key and a value (map)?

Actually, [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has several additional template parameters.  The third parameter is the hash.

> How could I modify this code so that, instead of returning a number
>   that defines the max num of points colinear, to actually storing any
>   point that is colinear in some form of a data structure that I may use
>   later?

With integer coordinates it is easier than with floating point (due to precision issues). I'm assuming you have an array of 2D points `p`.  One way would be, for every two pairs of points `p[i]` and `p[j]`, to let your key be the pair dX, dY *reduced to lowest form* (where  `dX = p[j].x - p[i].x` and `dY = p[j].y - p[i].y`).  Then your value could be a `std::set<int>` which contains the indices `i` and `j` that match.